# I have no Java Enterprise in Ultimate IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have downloaded the Ultimate intelliJ on Linux but I can't chose Java Entreprise when starting a project.
What am I missing?

Comment: Did you accidentally install the community version?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in the plugins, I had to go in the Settings, disable all the plugins and enable them again, as simple as that..
Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Choose **File → New → Project** and choose there **Java Enterprise**:

[image]